# Update UI from Task with Action

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to update a WPF `Window` from a `Task` with the following code

```
public void DoStuff() 
{

    View.LogFenster logFenster = new View.LogFenster(logViewModel);            

    logFenster.Show();

    Action<string> loaderStatusAction = s => logViewModel.LogText += s + "\n";

    List<item> items = LoaderTask(loaderStatusAction ).Result;

}

async Task<List<item>> LoaderTask(Action<string> loaderStatusChanged )
{
        for (int i = 5; i < 90; i++)
        {
            loaderStatusChanged($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}: i loop");
        }

}
```

But the `Window` bound to `logViewModel` is only updated, once `DoStuff` has finished, and not in between. Binding works, as the `Window` shows the 85 lines all at once afterwards.

How can I update the `Window` everytime `loaderStatusChanged` is fired?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use invoke the asynchronous method correctly using `await` instead of `Task.Result`. `Task.Result` will invoke the async method synchronously on the UI thread, which will freeze the UI as it has no free resources to update the layout.

```
public async Task DoStuff() 
{
  View.LogFenster logFenster = new View.LogFenster(logViewModel);            
  logFenster.Show();

  Action<string> loaderStatusAction = s => logViewModel.LogText += s + "\n";
  List<item> items = await LoaderTask(loaderStatusAction);    
}
```

If `DoStuff` is an event handler, then the signature must change to:

```
public async void DoStuff()
```

The carefree progress report pattern recommends the use of `IProgress<T>`:

```
public async Task DoStuff() 
{
  View.LogFenster logFenster = new View.LogFenster(logViewModel);            
  logFenster.Show();

  var progressReporter = new Progress<string>(s => logViewModel.LogText += s + "\n");
  List<item> items = await LoaderTask(progressReporter);    
}

async Task LoaderTask(IProgress<string> progressReporter)
{
  await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      for (int i = 5; i < 90; i++)
      {
        progressReporter.Report($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}: i loop");
      }
    });
}
```